# Negative effects of setting nginx workers too high

Tags: nginx, performance, performance-tuning

I've seen numerous posts advising how to set nginx's `worker_processes`, but very few detailing what happens when this is set too high. I'm about to run some benchmarks, but I'd appreciate advice on what I should expect. If I have one core (two hardware threads) available to nginx, what metrics would suffer if I changed `worker_processes` from 2 to 24?

Off the top of my head I'd expect CPU contention to cause lowered throughput and higher latencies. Is this correct? Would any other metrics be expected suffer noticeably - what else should I be benchmarking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `worker_processes` directive determines how many child processes / forks nginx will spawn from your master process. 24 processes would only make sense if you have 24 CPU cores (or at least 24 virtual CPU cores in case of Hyper Threading (HT) technology, still 12 cores though).

> CPU contention

Definitely, yes and this is going to be your greatest problem.

> Would any other metrics be expected suffer noticeably - what else should I be benchmarking?

Your operating system will have to manage those processes as well. Your overall performance will suffer and it should be obviously visible in memory usage (although not much).

If you are benchmarking, increase the amount of connections each process is allowed to handle. This will increase your throughput but will not put higher load on your hardware by simply throwing more and more processes at it.

Comment: Good general advice, although I was hoping for something more specific. For my benchmarks, the only statistically significant difference between `workers == available hardware threads` and `workers == 24 * available hardware threads` I could find was additional CPU usage (~10-15%) and server throughput (reduction of 10% when using too many workers)

Comment: If 10 % additional CPU and RAM (throughput/file descriptors) aren't statistically significant, than I don't know what is. ;)

Comment: They were the *only* ss metric, you may have misread my comment

Comment: Oh, you're right. But as I said, those are the only devices that are utilized and it makes total sense.

Comment: Yea, just glad to have it confirmed by data though. I also expected sig differences in interrupts as processors coordinated more, but nope.

Comment: I guess this would only happen with a slow CPU. Today's CPUs are so extremely fast that they can switch fast enough to prevent this.